# Applescript: Passing track metadata from text file to broadcast streaming app

Tags: applescript, metadata, broadcast

I know virtually nothing about AppleScript and could do with some help.

While running, my broadcast playout system (MegaSeg) writes details of the track currently playing to a textfile called "NowPlaying" which contains solely the following contents, each on its own line and without square brackets:

```
Title: [title]
Artist: [artist]
Album: [album]
Time: [time in some format or other]
```

I want to pass this to my broadcast streamer LadioCast, which can be addressed via AppleScript, so that it sends info on what is playing to the streaming server.
MegaSeg doesn't support Applescript calls like 'tell application "MegaSeg"... set trackName to name of current track' so I can't do it that way. I have no idea about how to do this.

If we imagine that I was able to grab that info, this is what I would do with it:

```
set lastName to ""
set lastArtist to ""
set lastAlbum to ""
repeat

    ** insert missing file reading section here
    ** in the following, "title", "artist" and "album" are from the text file **
    set trackName to title
    set trackArtist to artist
    set trackAlbum to album
    ** end of missing section

    if trackName is not lastName and trackArtist is not lastArtist and trackAlbum is not lastAlbum then
        set lastName to trackName
        set lastArtist to trackArtist
        set lastAlbum to trackAlbum
        tell application "LadioCast"
            set metadata song to trackName & " – " & trackArtist & " – " & trackAlbum
        end tell
    end if
    delay 15
end repeat
```

Thanks in advance.
--Richard E

===

I tried the suggestions from @DigiMonk and they were very helpful, but not all of them worked. First, the file is in a specific location and not on the desktop; second, I could not get 'trim_line' to work at all - I got "script does not understand trim_line message". However the text in the file seems to be already trimmed.

The script below *nearly* works; when run from the Applescript Editor it does seem to get the Title, Artist and Album into the variables. However when I try running it from LadioCast I get an EOF -39 error. More importantly, as soon as I run this, MegaSeg stops updating the file, forever. I am presumably locking the file to read from it and stopping MegaSeg writing to it. How do I avoid this?

```
set lastName to ""
set lastArtist to ""
set lastAlbum to ""
set lastTime to ""
set trackName to ""
set trackArtist to ""
set trackAlbum to ""
set sourcePath to ""

repeat

    set sourcePath to open for access file "Library:MegaSeg User Data:Logs:Logs for MegaSeg System (4):NowPlaying"
    set thisText to read sourcePath as text
    close access file "Library:MegaSeg User Data:Logs:Logs for MegaSeg System (4):NowPlaying"

    set the paragraphList to every paragraph of thisText

    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in paragraphList
        set thisItem to item i of paragraphList

        if thisItem starts with "Title:" then

            set x to the offset of "Title:" in thisItem
            set trackName to (text (x + 6) thru -1 of thisItem)

        else if thisItem starts with "Artist:" then
            set x to the offset of "Artist:" in thisItem
            set trackArtist to (text (x + 7) thru -1 of thisItem)

        else if thisItem starts with "Album:" then
            set x to the offset of "Album:" in thisItem
            set trackAlbum to (text (x + 6) thru -1 of thisItem)

        end if

    end repeat

    if trackName is not lastName and trackArtist is not lastArtist and trackAlbum is not lastAlbum then
        set lastName to trackName
        set lastArtist to trackArtist
        set lastAlbum to trackAlbum
        tell application "LadioCast"
            set metadata song to trackName & " – " & trackArtist & " – " & trackAlbum
        end tell
    end if
    delay 15

end repeat
```

Comment: So your'e question is: you have this existing text file and you want to squeeze the Title/Artist/Album/Time out. This is the problem your'e asking for help. Am I right?

Comment: @DigiMonk, Yes, the playout system continually updates the "NowPlaying" file with the Title, Artist and Album currently being played (it also includes the time which I don't need). Each is on its own line and is not delimited other than by the label (eg "Title:") at the front and the <CR> at the end. I want to get Title, Artist and Album into Applescript variables trackName, trackArtist and trackAlbum and send them to the streaming app using the form

`tell application "LadioCast"
            set metadata song to trackName & " – " & trackArtist & " – " & trackAlbum
        end tell`

Comment: @DigiMonk... I have added a partial solution to the bottom of my original question - I don't see any other way to do it! Your suggestions provided very helpful pointers but I am not quite there yet. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: BTW: in AppleScript Editor's Preferences one can enable the Script-Assistant (does Code Completion with the Escape-Key). And: CTRL-Click into a script shows a menu with Code-Snippets. That is often helpful.

Comment: I would implement the file-reading like in the sub-routine showed. There's a reason it's in a try - block: so it can catch errors and, if any, close the file! Thats very urgent.

Comment: It's tricky. That app owns the file and writes to it while the script reads from it every 15 seconds.

Comment: What do you mean with "...running it from LadioCast". From the System-Script-Menu?

Comment: @DigiMonk: Thanks for helpful comments. a) Yr original used "path to desktop" but file is in a specific location that "path to" doesn't work for. b) Fact that once script has looked at file it is no longer updated is obviously terminal! Data is also written to an HTML file in the same dir - would this be better? c) LadioCast has an Events pane in its Streamer config. It has a field called "Event Handler Applescript" (with Choose Script... button: I select script there); and fields for "Event Handler Names": "Connected", "Disconnected" and "Disconnected with error."?? Will try yr other points.

Comment: @DigiMonk Also, could not get trim_line to work at all... always complained that "script didn't understand trim_line message".

Sorry, I missed the readFile section of your answer, too busy trying to get it to find the file in its location :( Will try again using those ideas.

Note also two sets of variables - previous and current - this is to test if track has changed: if it hasn't we do not want to re-send to server (servers hate too many updates, must be one per track).

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps: (feed sourcePath with the path to your NowPlaying.txt file)

```
set sourcePath to (path to desktop) & "NowPlaying.txt" as text

set thisText to my readFile(sourcePath)

set the paragraphList to every paragraph of thisText

set lastName to ""
set lastArtist to ""
set lastAlbum to ""
set lastTime to ""

repeat with i from 1 to number of items in paragraphList
    set thisItem to item i of paragraphList
    --log thisItem

    if thisItem starts with "Title:" then

        set x to the offset of "Title:" in thisItem
        set y to (text (x + 6) thru -1 of thisItem)
        set lastName to my trim_line(y, " ", 2)

    else if thisItem starts with "Artist:" then
        set x to the offset of "Artist:" in thisItem
        set y to (text (x + 7) thru -1 of thisItem)
        set lastArtist to my trim_line(y, " ", 2)

    else if thisItem starts with "Album:" then
        set x to the offset of "Album:" in thisItem
        set y to (text (x + 6) thru -1 of thisItem)
        set lastAlbum to my trim_line(y, " ", 2)

    else if thisItem starts with "Time:" then
        set x to the offset of "Time:" in thisItem
        set y to (text (x + 5) thru -1 of thisItem)
        set lastTime to my trim_line(y, " ", 2)

    end if


end repeat

log "lastName = '" & lastName & "'"
log "lastArtist = '" & lastArtist & "'"
log "lastAlbum = '" & lastAlbum & "'"



on readFile(thisFile)
    set thisFile to thisFile as text
    if thisFile is "" then return ""
    try
        set fi to open for access file the thisFile
        set myData to read fi as text
        close access file the thisFile
        return myData
    on error
        try
            close access file the thisFile
            return ""
        end try
    end try
end readFile

on trim_line(this_text, trim_chars, trim_indicator)
    -- 0 = beginning, 1 = end, 2 = both
    set x to the length of the trim_chars
    -- TRIM BEGINNING
    if the trim_indicator is in {0, 2} then
        repeat while this_text begins with the trim_chars
            try
                set this_text to characters (x + 1) thru -1 of this_text as string
            on error
                -- the text contains nothing but the trim characters
                return ""
            end try
        end repeat
    end if
    -- TRIM ENDING
    if the trim_indicator is in {1, 2} then
        repeat while this_text ends with the trim_chars
            try
                set this_text to characters 1 thru -(x + 1) of this_text as string
            on error
                -- the text contains nothing but the trim characters
                return ""
            end try
        end repeat
    end if
    return this_text
end trim_line
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm studying it and it looks like a good start point. I wanted to maintain two sets of variables. lastName, lastArtist, lastAlbum are the previous values and trackName, trackArtist, trackAlbum are the current values. The script must ONLY update the streamer when the metadata in NowPlaying changes (it causes trouble to update too often). 

I don't see in your script how it writes to the streamer. I was going to use "tell application" and the expression "metadata song" which can take the format I want. However I think I can add this.

Comment: thanks in particular for the info on reading and grabbing specific text from the file. That was the main bit I was missing.

Comment: My file is in a specific location and not on the desktop so I had to alter that. In addition I was unable to get 'trim_line' to work at all - luckily the content seems to be already trimmed. Here is what I have so far: